# Calling stored procedures background operations in DB2 LUW

Tags: db2-luw

I'm wondering what happen in background  when I'm calling  stored procedures in DB2 9.7 ?
I mean which catalog tables ,related to this action?
Which DB2 packages run after calling a sp?
And also any addition information ,associated with this matter
Thank you in advance

Comment: This question as it is now is too broad. You may want to be more specific about what you need to know and why.

Comment: Actually, I want to measure the cost of calling SP compare to run direct sql statement,especially for consuming resources not security or consuming bandwidth.

Comment: For that you can use the [activity event monitor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/t0058531.html)

Comment: Yes I can,but I want to know the flow of calling Sp.Do you know about that?